# Nvidia drivers apparently broke Xorg configuration

Tags: nvidia, xorg, screen, xserver, xorg.conf

I installed 15.04 on a new Lenovo Edge 2-1580 with an Nvidia GeForce 940M. It appears I need some help with Xorg.

1. The computer will not display lightdm when booting normally. (gdm does not even display that, only a blank screen.) Rather, I get an window displaying the "The system is running in low-graphics mode" error message.
2. Booting into Advanced Options for Ubuntu > recovery mode > failsafeX generates the following error:

`Fatal server error:
[   182.115] (EE) no screens found(EE) 
[   182.115] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
         at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[   182.115] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.failsafe.log" for additional information.
[   182.115] (EE) 
[   182.122] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.`

3. But booting into Advanced Options for Ubuntu > recovery mode > resume generates a viable graphical environment. Even the external HDMI monitor works, but obviously I can't adjust any of the displays or monitor settings.
4. It looks like I need to use the xserver-xorg-video-nouveau drivers, not the proprietary nvidia drivers. I got into this situation after I used Software & Updates > Additional Drivers to install the nvidia drivers. Using the nvidia drivers broke every graphical environment beyond lightdm (this may have been complicated by the use of an external HDMI monitor).

I'm pasting lspci. Asubuntu won't let me paste the full Xorg log files.

`lspci -nnk | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Integrated Graphics [8086:1916] (rev 07)`

`lspci -nnk | grep NV
01:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 940M] [10de:1347] (rev a2)`

`cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "layout"
    Screen 0 "nvidia"
    Inactive "intel"
EndSection
Section "Device"
    Identifier "intel"
    Driver "modesetting"
    BusID "PCI:0@0:2:0"
    Option "AccelMethod" "None"
EndSection
Section "Screen"
    Identifier "intel"
    Device "intel"
EndSection
Section "Device"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Driver "nvidia"
    BusID "PCI:1@0:0:0"
    Option "ConstrainCursor" "off"
EndSection
Section "Screen"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Device "nvidia"
    Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "on"
    Option "IgnoreDisplayDevices" "CRT"
EndSection`

Comment: This fix ended up being trivial. I made it before seeing cl-netbox's answer. I simply used [Nouveau's suggestion for /etc/X11/xorg.conf](http://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/UbuntuPackages/): `Section "Device"
Identifier "n"
Driver "nouveau"
EndSection`

Answer (score 0):

Install the latest stable NVIDIA drivers 352 which support GEFORCE 940M.

Highlight the Ubuntu entry in the GRUB boot menu and press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line - press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

On login screen press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> ... enter  user name and password ...

Execute these commands :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352 nvidia -prime
sudo reboot
```

Generally you should use the drivers from the official Ubuntu repositories.
In case the drivers don't work as expected ... install the NVIDIA drivers 358.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-358 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```